# Check if elements of different ArrayLists share position

Tags: java, arraylist, coordinates

I am programming a probe that moves through a 2D board in Java. To do this, I have two ArrayLists of Integer that contain the path that the probe has followed. The first ArrayList contains the x-coordinate, and the second one, the y-coordinate. What I would like to do is check whether the next tile of the movement has been visited or not, this is, whether the new x-coord and the new y-coord are in the corresponding ArrayList and share the same position.That way, if the new tile has been visited, I wouldn't move there. How could I possibly do this? I have tried with *indexOf* and *lastIndexOf*, but it doesn't work as each coordinate can be repeated an indefinite number of times. I also tried *.contains* but it didn't work either as I need that it is contained in both arrays in a specific position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty messy approach would be to find all indexes of matching x-coordinates and for each index found check whether the y-coordinate for the given index is equal to the `y` in question.

So given coordinates `x`, `y` and array lists `visitedX` and `visitedY` you could do something like this:

```
public static boolean isVisited(int x, int y){
  for(int i = 0; i < visitedX.size(), i++){
    if(visitedX.get(i) == x){
      if(visitedY.get(i) == y){
        return true;
      }
    }
   }
  return false;
}
```

But as Jack has mentioned you should reconsider your data structure as looping over the complete x-coordinates list is not very efficient (though you could reduce limits of outer `for` loop with usage of `visitedX.indexOf(x)` and `visitedX.lastIndexOf(x)` ).

Comment: I think I'll try this approach as it seems to be the perfect solution for my problem, thank you! And I know it is not efficient at all, but it is the only way to do it that I can understand as a newcomer to Java.

Comment: Glad I could provide some help. And though it might not be very elegant or elaborate I hope this approach is more 'hands down' and maybe easier to understand :) Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

First of all Java is object oriented so you should use objects. Why are you storing a coordinate in two separate arrays?

You can define your own type:

```
class Position implements Comparable<Position> {
  public final int x;
  public final int y;

  Position(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y; }
  @Override public int compareTo(Position other) { ... }
  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) { ... }
  @Override public int hashCode() { ... }
}
```

Then with this you can do whatever you want, for example

```
Set<Position> visited = new HashSet<Position>();
Map<Position, Integer> visitedWithSpecificPositionInPath = new HashMap<Position, Integer();
```

and so on.

Comment: The answer to you question is: because I'm new to Java and I didn't know any other way to do it. I'll try to understand your answer and apply it, thank you.